# Why does my twitter4j maven dependency not include TwitterStreamFactory?

Tags: java, twitter4j

I've been using twitter4j for months, doing simple getUserTimeline(), after creating TwitterFactory and Twitter instance with OAuth in Configuration. Works great.

But now I'd like to use the Streaming feature, TwitterStreamFactory. It is not included in my external library that maven is managing. I've included twitter4j via maven like they say, like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>[4.0,)</version>
</dependency>
```

I also tried changing the version to 4.0.7. The docs say TwitterStreamFactory is there since version 2.1.0, so why isn't it in my twitter4j library?

I'm viewing all the dependencies/external libraries via Intellij's view of them in the project. I don't see any other versions, or dependency conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [it is in `twitter4j` as of version 4.0.7](https://github.com/Twitter4J/Twitter4J/blob/4.0.7/twitter4j-stream/src/main/java/twitter4j/TwitterStreamFactory.java).

But as you can see, it is part of the `twitter4j-stream` artifact.  You'll want to use the [`twitter4j-stream` Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/classic/#artifactdetails%7Corg.twitter4j%7Ctwitter4j-stream%7C4.0.7%7Cjar) instead.

Comment: Thanks! Where is it noted that it's a separate artifact? I didn't see that anywhere in the docs or on twitter4j site

Comment: Look at the github.com link I posted, and note the `twitter4j-stream` directory.  I just looked at the `pom.xml` file to see what its `<artifactId>` was. Additionally, if you know the full classname of the class in question, you can search Maven Central for artifacts containing it: https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory%22

Comment: I have a followup question that I'll do as a separate question, as to why my stream filtering on a specific user isn't working...in case you know and want internet points...